# Magento 2: Is there an event when company gets created or can anyone tell me how to create custom event when company is created?

Tags: event-observer, magento2.4, company

I wanted to automate the process of company approval, so I setup the status column default value in company table as 1. Now I want to send an email to the person as soon as the company is created. I was wondering if there is any event associated with company creation or if someone can tell how can I create any custom event that will be wonderful.

Comment: are you using magento 2.4's default B2B feature?

Comment: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/customers/account-company-create.html  -- this one?

Comment: @GohilRajesh Yes, I am using magento 2.4 default B2B feature.